# Summary of manyglm model objects running too slowly in R; can I speed them up?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, modeling, multivariate-regression, parallel-computing

I have implemented two independent multivariate abundance regressions, both of which use the `manyglm` function in the `mvabund` package in R.

One regression fits 17 predictors to the abundances of 62 different bird species, while the other regression fits 15 predictors to the abundances of 158 different plant species, which makes each of these applications dependent on multivariate approaches.

Dataset sizes: 160 rows x 79 columns (bird data) and 4000 rows x 173 columns (plant data).

Computation: both regressions are being run on a single 64-bit Windows system with up to 8GB of RAM and one of four core processors.

Example code:

```
global.glm.birds<- manyglm(birdabund~x$Easting+x$Sex+x$Time+x$DistanceCode+
                         x$Detection+x$CounterSing+x$SkyCode+x$WindCode+x$Treatment+
                         x$AWS+x$SOC+x$AMWTD+x$Elevation+x$Aspect+x$medianTmeanSummer+
                         x$stdevPrecipSummer+x$HarvestIntensity,family="negative.binomial",p.uni="adjusted")
```

When I go to summarize the model fit objects from `manyglm` with the `summary` or `summary.manyglm` functions, the routines take inordinately long to finish computing and report the results to the console window. These processes sometimes can take days, even weeks, to complete.

Example code:

```
summary(global.glm.birds)
summary.manyglm(global.glm.birds)
```

Does anyone know how I can speed these summary processes up? Are there any parallelized routines out there for R's `summary` functions?

Here's my `sessionInfo()` in R:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] nimble_0.6-3       MVN_4.0.2          mvabund_3.11.9     car_2.0-25         MASS_7.3-40        ggplot2_2.0.0      matrixStats_0.14.2
 [8] reshape_0.8.6      vegan_2.3-3        lattice_0.20-31    permute_0.8-4      rgdal_1.1-10       sp_1.2-3           plyr_1.8.3        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] mclust_5.2            Rcpp_0.11.6           vcd_1.4-3             mvtnorm_1.0-2         class_7.3-12          zoo_1.7-12           
 [7] lmtest_0.9-33         psych_1.5.8           tweedie_2.2.1         VIM_4.6.0             chron_2.3-47          stats4_3.2.0         
[13] pcaPP_1.9-61          coda_0.17-1           e1071_1.6-7           diptest_0.75-7        minqa_1.2.4           data.table_1.9.6     
[19] SparseM_1.6           nloptr_1.0.4          kernlab_0.9-25        robCompositions_2.0.2 Matrix_1.2-0          moments_0.14         
[25] splines_3.2.0         lme4_1.1-7            statmod_1.4.26        sROC_0.1-2            igraph_1.0.1          munsell_0.4.2        
[31] mnormt_1.5-3          mgcv_1.8-6            nnet_7.3-9            rrcov_1.4-3           laeken_0.4.6          grid_3.2.0           
[37] nlme_3.1-120          GGally_1.0.1          gtable_0.1.2          magrittr_1.5          scales_0.3.0          mvoutlier_2.0.6      
[43] flexmix_2.3-13        robustbase_0.92-5     pls_2.5-0             boot_1.3-16           nortest_1.0-4         tools_3.2.0          
[49] fpc_2.1-10            trimcluster_0.1-2     DEoptimR_1.0-3        cvTools_0.3.2         parallel_3.2.0        pbkrtest_0.4-2       
[55] colorspace_1.2-6      cluster_2.0.3         prabclus_2.2-6        sgeostat_1.0-27       quantreg_5.11         modeltools_0.2-21
```

Thanks for any help, in advance.

-Andrew

Comment: The biggest data set doesn't seem all that big, just a bit over 5.5 Mbytes. Can you check the total memory occupation of your session? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395270/determining-memory-usage-of-objects) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) if you're unsure on how to do it. Also, check that, alongside with R, you don't have other applications open which consume a lot of RAM - basically, you must be sure that the huge computing time is not due to Windows swapping from disk.

Answer (score 3):

"Weeks" sounds definitely too much. I don't have experience with `mvabund`, but the package authors acknowledge that `anova.manyglm` and other functions from `mvabund` [can be quite slow](https://rdrr.io/rforge/mvabund/man/mvabund-package.html).  This could be the case for `summary.manyglm` too, because, according to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179557/resampling-under-the-null-versus-the-alternative-hypothesis), `anova.manyglm` and `summary.manyglm` both perform some kind of resampling. That having being said, I cannot see how a computational time of weeks could be justified, expecially noting that your data set is not big at all:

```
foobar <- matrix(rnorm(4000*173),4000,173)
format(object.size(foobar), unit = "auto")
#[1] "5.3 Mb"
```

I strongly suspect that the problem is due to poor coding of the package functions: maybe objects are being grown inside loops, vectorization is not being exploited, or other sins mentioned in the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). If this is the case, then there's very little you can do, apart from using another package or writing the R code you need by yourself. Anyway, to leave no stone unturned, let's go step by step:

1. Such huge slowdowns in Windows are usually due to virtual memory usage, a.k.a. disk swapping. I don't see how such a small dataset may lead to disk swapping, but just to be 100% sure that disk swapping is not the culprit here, [check the total memory used by the R session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session). It could also be that memory-hungry Windows applications are running at the same time as your R session, and the combined memory usage could exceed you physical memory. To make sure that this isn't the case, monitor the total memory usage with the Windows Task Manager.
2. Once you're sure that virtual memory is **not** being used by Windows, try to use an R build which is linked to high-performance BLAS libraries for your CPU, and which is compiled to take advantage of multiple cores. I have a very good experience with [Microsoft R Open](https://mran.microsoft.com/open/). It's easy to install and 100% compatible with CRAN R: the only nag is that the default package repository is not updated as often as the CRAN repository. However, if this is a problem for you, you can easily alter defaults so that packages are installed from the CRAN repository, instead than from the MRO one. You will also get the added bonus of getting an up-to-date R installation, and updated package version: your R version is over one year old. Maybe the up-to-date version of `mvabund` has fixed the speed issues.
3. If all else fails, I would try to understand if the issue is with the `anova.manyglm` algorithm. Maybe its operation count scales horribly with dataframe size: you could generate random dataframes of increasing size (or maybe just get random subsamples from your actual data set) and use the `microbenchmark` package to study the increase in computational time with size. If the scaling is particularly bad, then, as I said before, I don't see any other solutions apart from using another package or writing your own R code.

Comment: @Andrew did my answer address some of your issues?